# strange mysql performance

Tags: sql, mysql, performance

I've been conducting some mysql performance tests and have yield very strange results. I am running a query across the following mysql versions: 5.0.91, 5.1.52, 5.1.52 with innodb-plugin, and 5.5.7.

Here is the execution time for the query on each version:

```
version            time
------------------------
5.0:               95s
5.1:               122s
5.1 innodb-plugin: 159s
5.5:               127s
```

I am testing against same data (50M records in one table), on Windows 2003. Database is using InnoDB engine on all versions.

I don't understand how MySQL 5.0 would be the fastest, how the innodb-plugin yields worst results than when not in use and how 5.5 is so similar to 5.1 in performance.

Anyone run into this? Anyone have suggestions?

Here are my.ini configs:

- query_cache_size=0
- table_cache=256
- tmp_table_size=2000M
- thread_cache_size=32
- innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=128M
- innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
- innodb_log_buffer_size=4M
- innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G
- innodb_log_file_size=256M
- innodb_thread_concurrency=32

innodb-plugin specific:

- ignore_builtin_innodb
- plugin-load=innodb=ha_innodb_plugin.dll;innodb_trx=ha_innodb_plugin.dll;innodb_locks=ha_innodb_plugin.dll;innodb_lock_waits=ha_innodb_plugin.dll;innodb_cmp=ha_innodb_plugin.dll;innodb_cmp_reset=ha_innodb_plugin.dll;innodb_cmpmem=ha_innodb_plugin.dll;innodb_cmpmem_reset=ha_innodb_plugin.dll
- innodb_file_format=Barracuda
- innodb_io_capacity=400

Comment: Post your benchmark code. + my.ini params

Answer (score 2):

Are these all the same engine? (InnoDB or MyISAM?)
Is the cache flushed or used in these queries?
You have described your tests with so little detail, it is very hard to begin to identify why you might be seeing odd results.

Maybe take a look at some of the methodology used here: [Testing performance of queries in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756100/testing-performance-of-queries-in-mysl)

I will also add that different optimizations in mysql versions might result in any single query being slower or faster between them.  I do not generally see test suites relying on a single query for this very reason.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info -> what does the query look like?

Comment: all these are the same engine: innodb. how do i know if cache is flushed? I set query_cache_size to 0 so as to have no caching.

Comment: query_cache_size=0 does not prevent caching, it just turns off the query cache. Caching in the engine still happens.

Answer (score 1):

I have some suggestions:

1. For IO-bound benchmark, before each test run, load the entire data from a dump into the server. Then shut the server down and start it up again. The initial queries in your test suite will need to do physical IO to read the blocks. Subsequent ones will benefit from the earlier ones bringing pages into cache.
2. For memory-bound benchmark, do the same, but don't shut the server down after loading the data.

I am assuming of course, that such a small (50M rows == small) table will fit into memory (Your 8G buffer pool divided by 50M rows = 170 bytes average per row). If it doesn't, revise the above.

If you are interested in the newer innodb engine, be sure to use "Barracuda" file format (which needs to be set in the config file, at server startup, before you create any tables) to take advantage of the new features. Then you can test with compression enabled (which will make the data smaller and may at least speed up the IO-bound tests a bit).

Depending on your application, you may also want to try it on a large table. This will of course need a lot longer to run (presumably loading 50M rows is pretty quick).