# Bench-marking SQL Query

Tags: mysql, benchmarking

I have two MySQL queries that return the same result.
I would like to know which one is the best or the optimized solution?
I am aware of MySQL profiling, I only concern about **Having** alternatives?

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM users_courses 
    GROUP BY user_id 
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
)
```

OR

```sql
SELECT coding_test.users.name 
FROM coding_test.users_courses
INNER JOIN coding_test.users ON coding_test.users.id = coding_test.users_courses.user_id 
GROUP BY coding_test.users.name 
HAVING COUNT(coding_test.users_courses.course_id) >= 2
```

Thank you

Comment: The one that's faster is better. The reason I answered like that (completely unusable) is because you didn't provide sufficient information. Did you want to ask *how* to benchmark the queries? Using a subquery or a `JOIN` is effectively one and the same thing (MySQL's engine is going to interpret and execute both in exactly the same way). Both queries will be equally slow due to `having` clause.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing performance of queries in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756100/testing-performance-of-queries-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

I was searching about MySQL benchmarking, as it was a doubt of my own too, and found another very interesting answer that can help you with even more complex queries:

[Testing performance of queries in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756100/testing-performance-of-queries-in-mysql)

Hope it helps!