# Best way to get list of element combinations from two mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have two tables:

1. Table "products"

| ID | Name | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product A | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | Product B | 20 | 10 |

2. Table "promotions"

| ID | Product ID | Type | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | discount | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | discount | 8 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | outlet | 10 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | outlet | 10 | 0 |

From tables above I can see that:

1. I have 10 pieces of Product A with regular price 10$
2. I have 3 pieces of Product A with discounted price 5$
3. I have 2 pieces of Product A with discounted price 8$
4. I have 3 pieces of Product A with outlet price 3$
5. I have 10 pieces of Product B with regular price 20$
6. I have 0 pieces of Product B with outlet price 3$.

What is the most efficient way to get all combinations of available products?

My solution was with three UNION SQL querys, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  (<<all products in reular prices>>)
  UNION ALL
  (<<all products in discount prices>>)
  UNION ALL
  (<<all products in outlet prices>>)
) as tmp
```

Everything works fine, I am just wondering if this is the best way or is it better to use LEFT or RIGHT JOIN. Of course this is just an example, my tables have 20.000+ lines so I am looking for fastest way to list results.

Comment: Part of your SQL is missing. But in any case, you would need to have different queries then you can run all variants and compare the speeds with each other. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/2756100 and the like

Comment: you don't need separate queries for discount and outlet, since they're both in the `promotions` table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing performance of queries in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756100/testing-performance-of-queries-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

One option could be:

- first apply a `UNION` between "*Products*" and "*Promotions*" on matching columns
- then `JOIN` back with "*Products*" to retrieve the products name

```
SELECT prices.ProductID,
       Products.Name,
       prices.Type,
       prices.Price,
       prices.Quantity
FROM (SELECT ID        AS ProductID,
             'regular' AS Type,
             Price,
             Quantity
      FROM Products
      UNION
      SELECT ProductID,
             Type,
             Price,
             Quantity
      FROM Promotions                 ) prices
INNER JOIN Products 
        ON prices.ProductID = Products.ID
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/boxtEExp2NyYgce3FRojrF/0).